# windows 7 mobile css media query

Tags: css, windows-phone-7, mobile, media-queries

How can I target Windows phone 7 with css media queries?

Right now, I am trying this with no luck.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 5px)  { // css here }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/iemobile/archive/2010/12/08/targeting-mobile-optimized-css-at-windows-phone-7.aspx